# Read lines from text file in go, with bufio.reader

Tags: go

```
for {
    v, err = nextNum(reader, ' ')
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    w, err = nextNum(reader, ' ')
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    cost, err = nextNum(reader, '\n')
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(v, w, cost)
}
```

My text file consists of three coloumns and n rows. The first time nextNum is called the number in the first row and first column will be returned, next time the number in the second column and first row, and so on. My problem is when i get to the end and i call nextNum for the last time then i will recieve an EOF error and the last line will never get printed out, becuase break will be called before. Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

CHeers

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no new line in the last row in your file and it's simply ending with `EOF`. It his correct? As a result, the very last column is not being parsed correctly, as it doesn't end with an expected character (`\n`).

You didn't show us exactly how you're using `bufio.Reader`, but either way you will need to account for missing new line at the end of file (it's up to you whether treat it as an error or not). Using methods like `bufio.Reader.ReadString` with `\n` delimiter won't treat `EOF` as the end-of-line automatically, but will return you a valid content along with `EOF` (i.e. you can get both data and error at the same call – note this is a different behaviour than in `bufio.Reader.Read`).

Saying this, it might be beneficial for you to use the [`csv`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) package instead. It will solve the `EOF` problem and you could also benefit from some nicer error messages on unexpected number of columns. The additional features like comments or quotes might be good or bad for your purposes.

[Example:](https://play.golang.org/p/emFblKknGu)

```
// No line break at the end, pure EOF (still works)
data := "one 1\ntwo 2\nthree 3\nfour 4"

// You can wrap your file reader with bufio.Reader here
cr := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader([]byte(data)))
cr.Comma = ' '
cr.FieldsPerRecord = 2

var err error
for err == nil {
    var columns []string
    if columns, err = cr.Read(); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(columns)
        // err = processRow(columns)
    }
}
if err != io.EOF {
    // Parse error
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [bufio docs](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read):

> At EOF, the count will be zero and err will be io.EOF

So you can simply test for that. Like change your `if err != nil` to `if err != nil && err != io.EOF`

or

```
if err == io.EOF {
    fmt.Println(v, w, cost)
    break
}
if err != nil {
    break
}
fmt.Println(v, w, cost)
```

Though you really should do something with the error and not just ignore it.

Comment: The thing is. My for loop is dependent on that an EOF will happen eventually. Thats how i tell my loop that the entire document has been scanned.

Comment: The second option I provided will (now that it's edited) do that - print the last line and then exit the loop.